# Is there a O(log n) algorithm for matrix exponentiation?

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, matrices

Is there an algorithm to raise a matrix to the $n$th power in $O(\log n)$ time?

I have been searching online, but have been unsuccessful thus far.

Comment: You mean you have a fixed size matrix? in fact if your matrix is of size $m$ you can't expect to find $O(log \  n)$ algorithm.

Comment: People usually refer to this problem as matrix powering. Matrix exponentiation means finding $e^X$

Comment: @Shitikanth Ok, thanks. I shall change that now.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is the pseudocode for an $O(\lg n)$ matrix exponentiation algorithm. Note that the * operator denotes ordinary matrix multiplication.

```
MATHPOWER (M, n)
if n == 1
    then return M
else
    P = MATHPOWER (M, floor(n/2))
    if n mod 2 == 0
        then return P * P
    else
        return P * P * M
```

Comment: For people coming from the future, this is a terrible answer. It does work O(n^3 * log(n)) when there are O(n^3) algorithms instead. See the answer from Yuval below. As practical matter, this is normally done by SVD decomposition, then raising the N elements of the D matrix to the power, and the multiplying the matrix back out again.

Comment: @Michael O, I think you really missed the point. You misunderstood what the OP was asking for, i.e., how to raise a matrix to the $n$-th power in $O(\lg n) steps$. The key is that the OP is only requiring that the number of steps done is  $O(\lg n)$, not the overall complexity since this would require taking into account the matrix order as well.

Comment: It is obvious that the proposed divide and conquer approach has worst-case complexity $O(\lg n)$ only when the matrix order is $O(1)$, since in this case the corresponding recurrence equation is $T(n) = T(n/2) + O(1)$ (as an example, for a 3 x 3 matrix a matrix multiplication can be done using a constant number of scalar multiplications and additions). One possible application of the algorithm I gave, is to compute the $n$-th Fibonacci number, by tasing the matrix whose entries are $a_{11} = 1, a_{12} = 1, a_{21} = 1, a_{22} = 0$ to the $n$-th power.

Comment: Finally, note also that this was already sorted out and fully understood: just take a look at the comment to the question provided by @user742.

Comment: The point is that the reason that the OP failed to find algorithms for _O(lg n)_ is because there's readily available algorithms that are _O(1)_ (for fixed size matrices).

Comment: This is really interesting. Would you mind citing related papers in which these O(1) algorithms for fixed size matrices were introduced? The only related and recent paper I am aware of is the following, in which the authors provide algorithm for matrices of size 2x2 and 3x3, but their algorithms are not constant time: Esther Galby, Joël Ouaknine, and James Worrell. On matrix powering in low dimensions. Proceedings of STACS 15, LIPIcs 30, 2015. Thank you in advance.

Comment: The canonical method is: SVD to decompose the matrix in left, diagonal and right sub matrices. (O(1) as SVD is independent of the power). Power the diagonal matrix (scalar operation on each diagonal element, O(1) in n). Multiply the 3 resulting matrices back together. In total this is a constant number of matrix ops, independent of the power n. The non-SVD portion is also a constant number of floating point ops. (SVD may have a variable number of floating point ops, but only dependent on the matrix, not on n).

Comment: Wait, I forgot a restriction. This needs the matrix to be +ve semi-definate. If that's not the case, then it need to go via the jordan form. (Hmm. this is all covered in the answer from Yuval)

Comment: Thank you for describing the algorithm; however, you still need to raise a constant number of entries of the diagonal matrix to the $n$-th power. But powering just one scalar to the $n$-th power is not independent of $n$ and requires $O(\lg n)$. Therefore, your algorithm appears to be $O(\lg n)$ in the worst case even for matrices of constant size, but, as you noted, it will not work for $any$ matrix of constant size.

Comment: I described constant time via SVD because it's the normal case, but adding in conversion to jordan form is still a constant number of matrix ops. Raising a scalar to the _n_-th power is a constant time floating point operation. If you want to worry about the unlimited domain case, then you also need take into account that multiply is not constant time in the unlimited domain.

Comment: What you mean exactly? Assuming that arbitrary-precision arithmetic can be done in constant time (standard assumption in the RAM model), raising a scalar to the $n$-th power requires $O(\lg n$):  the naive algorithm requires $O(n)$. Otherwise, dropping the assumption, one must also take into account that, in each step, the cost of multiplying two $n$ digits numbers is not $O(1)$ but, to the best of my knowledge, $O(n \lg n)$ by using the 2019 algorithm of Harvey and van der Hoeven. In my case, I was analyzing the algorithm for small O(1) fixed size matrices, assuming the RAM model.

Answer (score 11):

There are two other algorithms which may or may not be relevant. The first algorithm [diagonalizes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix) your matrix (which is usually possible), writing it as $M = PDP^{-1}$, where $M,D$ in general may be complex-valued. You then compute $M=PD^nP^{-1}$. Note it's very easy to raise a diagonal matrix to the $n$th power. If $M$ is not diagonalizable, you find its Jordan form and proceed as before (now you also have to calculate some binomial coefficients). This algorithm is probably not numerically stable.

Another algorithm uses the fact that $M$ satisfies its characteristic polynomial (or even its minimal polynomial). Suppose $P(M) = 0$ for some $P$, say the characteristic polynomial. Then we can compute $M^n$ over $\mathbb{R}[M]/(P(M))$, and then substitute $M$. That means that we calculate $M^n$ as a polynomial, using the fact that $P(M) = 0$, and only at the end substitute the values of $M$. We could even precompute all the necessary powers of $M$ and all the values of $M^k \pmod{P(M)}$ for $k < 2\deg P-1$, and then this algorithm could be faster than the algorithm is Massimo Cafaro's answer. It might be more numerically stable than the previous algorithm.